# How can display the names of the fields in the design phase

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

How can view all the names of the fields in the table, at the stage of the code book, when you click on the button DOT (.) , 
Ex:

```
dim cn as new SqlConnection ="Data Source=USER-COM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Data1;Integrated Security=True"


dim Command as sqlCommand

Dim DataTable As New DataTable

Command.CommandText = "Select * From Table1"
Command.CommandType=CommandType.Text
Command.Connection = Cn
cn.open

DataAdaptor = New SqlDataAdapter(Command)
DataAdaptor.Fill (DataTable)
```

> ```
> Private function Field (NameField As FieldInTable ) 'Hair Is List Field In NameField
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there's no way to do what you want. At this point in the process, Visual Studio is little more than a text editor - it's not going to execute the SQL query for you to figure out the field names.

In order to achieve the ease of use you're trying for, you need to use something more modern, like Entity Framework.